# Raphael JS - Prevent text highlighting when clicking

Tags: javascript, css, raphael

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/p7Lze6nh/

Using Raphael JS 2.1.2 and I'm trying to disable text highlighting when an element is clicked. It does it on Chrome, but not on IE for some reason. I don't have FF on this laptop at the moment to test.

The code is relatively straightforward-

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 125, 125);
paper.canvas.style.backgroundColor = "Black";
var a = 0;

text1 = paper.text(10, 10, a).attr({"text-anchor":"start", fill:"white"});
rect1 = paper.rect(10, 50, 50, 50).attr({fill:"white"});

rect1.click(function(){
    inc()
});

function inc() {
    a++;
    text1.attr({text: a});
}
```

I've tried using the 'user-select: none' and other various CSS rules found via examples for the div containing the paper, but that didn't work. I've also tried using

```
text1.userSelect = "none";
```

...and the others directly into javascript, but I didn't get anywhere, either. I recall Cookie Clicker having this problem, but I can't seem to find the solution in the code. But, it also uses canvas instead of Raphael.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User select should work ok, but not in the format shown. You can't just set an object variable like that.

Using css styling, it can be done like this...

```
text {
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Lze6nh/1/)

and slightly different version setting class direct...

```
.donthighlight {
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
}

text1.node.setAttribute("class","donthighlight");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7Lze6nh/2/)

I guess be wary some older browsers may not support this, which is a reason Raphael is often used, and extend the css to include the other browsers.

Comment: Yes, the second example is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.